# ANTD Dropdown should not close when clicked on the Input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to implement a dropdown functionality using ANTD components such that:

1. When there is some text in the Input field, the dropdown should be displayed.
2. When I click outside the dropdown, the dropdown should close.
3. When I click on the dropdown menu, the dropdown should NOT close.
4. If there is no text on the Input field, the dropdown should NOT open.
5. **The dropdown should not close when clicked on the Input field if there is some text.**

I am unable to achieve the 5th requirement. Whenever I click on the Input field, the dropdown opens and closes as shown here:
[image]

This should not happen.

Sample working code:

```
state = {
    visible: false,
    searchInput: null
  };

handleVisibleChange = flag => {
    if (!this.isDefined(this.state.searchInput)) {
      this.removeDropdown();
    } else {
      this.setState({ visible: flag });
    }
  };

removeDropdown = () => {
  this.setState({ visible: false });
};

showDropdown = () => {
  this.setState({ visible: true });
};

checkInput = value => {
  if (this.isDefined(value)) {
    this.setState({ searchInput: value });
    this.showDropdown();
  } else {
    this.setState({ searchInput: null });
    this.removeDropdown();
  }
};

render() {
  const menu = (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item key="1">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">Clicking me will not close the menu also.</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="3">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
  return (
    <Dropdown
      overlay={menu}
      trigger={['click']}
      onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
      visible={this.state.visible}
    >
      <Search
        value={this.state.searchInput}
        onInput={e => this.checkInput(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Complete code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-srz4ml?file=index.js

I tried using `onBlur()` and `onFocus()` methods instead of `onVisibleChange()` but it is violating the 3rd requirement.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented a bit with this and there does not seem to be a super easy way to do this but I was able to make it work with some ugly state management. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-srz4ml-p6faxs?file=index.js
Hopefully you may come up with a cleaner solution.

```js
state = {
    searchInput: null,
    isVisable: false,
    clickedPrevState: false
  };

  render() {
    const getNewState = (prevState, event, value) => {
      console.log(prevState, event, value);
      let newState = { ...prevState, clickedPrevState: false };
      switch (event) {
        case 'input':
          newState.isVisable = value ? true : false;
          newState.searchInput = value;
          break;
        case 'clicked':
          if (prevState.searchInput) {
            newState.isVisable = true;
            newState.clickedPrevState = true; // used by next getNewState to determine if it was a click on input
          } else newState.isVisable = false;
          break;
        case 'change':
          if (prevState.searchInput && (value || prevState.clickedPrevState)) {
            newState.isVisable = true;
          } else newState.isVisable = false;
          break;
        default:
          newState.isVisable = false;
      }
      return newState;
    };

    const menu = (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item key="1">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">Clicking me will not close the menu also.</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
    return (
      <Dropdown
        overlay={menu}
        trigger={['click']}
        visible={this.state.isVisable}
        onVisibleChange={flag =>
          this.setState(prevstate => {
            return getNewState(prevstate, 'change', flag);
          })
        }
        onClick={e =>
          this.setState(prevstate => {
            return getNewState(prevstate, 'clicked');
          })
        }
      >
        <Search
          value={this.state.searchInput}
          onInput={e =>
            this.setState(prevstate => {
              return getNewState(prevstate, 'input', e.target.value);
            })
          }
        />
      </Dropdown>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this same logic in my project, but first the `onVisibleChange` is getting triggered and then the `onClick` event (In the given code sandbox the order is reversed). So when I click on the search box first the **change** event is setting `clickedPrevState` to false, and then the **clicked** event is setting the state to true. Therefore, if I click outside the `clickedPrevState` is still true at this point and the dropdown is not disappearing. If I click again then it closes. Is there a possibility to change the order of triggering `onClick` and `onVisisbleChange` events?

Comment: Interesting that it would be reversed. It might be different versions of antd. You would have to change the logic if thats the case. Just looking at it without testing it I think it should work by just removing all the logic with clickedPrevState. When I test it the events seem to be part of the same render cycle so should work without causing flickering of the menu.